# Play cable TV server content from PC

Tags: windows-7, cable, tv, dlna

I am renting [this DLNA-enabled set-top box](http://sol.panasonic.biz/file.jsp?catv-support/manual/pdf/tz-hdw610.pdf) from my cable TV provider.
[This documentation](http://news.panasonic.com/jp/press/data/2012/11/jn121119-1/jn121119-1.html) mentions it is able to stream TV content to my PC (sorry, only available in Japanese, search "別の部屋のテレビやパソコンで再生して楽しむことができます").
I am indeed able to watch content via my smartphone using [this application](http://www.digion.com/catv/).

If I can play content from my smartphone, I believe I can similarly play content from my laptop. Programs such as VLC and Windows Media Player indeed show the server in the list of available.
With Windows Media Player, I can even see the list of available programs. However, trying to play any of them only gets me a message for [error C00D119D](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/c00d119d) ("metafile playlist isn't valid").

Is there any software or specific setting that I can use to play content from my DLNA set-top box on my PC?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.

Comment: My guess is that is not allowed due to licensing reasons/piracy/etc. The cable TV provider should be able to control this.